# Smallest and biggest value in slice of 3D array

Tags: c#, max, min, multidimensional-array

I have a 3d-array `double[,,] numbers = new double[x,y,z];` and now if one imagines the 3d-array to look like a cube with numbers I need to find the smallest and biggest value of every slice along all three directions.

It is of course easy to do by simply looping over it, but does C# have any functions to find the smallest and biggest value in a slice?

To explain it a bit further, maybe this "unreal" code will help:

```
int i;

double[] xmin = new double[x];
double[] xmax = new double[x];
double[] ymin = new double[y];
double[] ymax = new double[y];
double[] zmin = new double[z];
double[] zmax = new double[z];

for(i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    MinOf(numbers[i, y, z]) = xmin[i];
    MaxOf(numbers[i, y, z]) = xmax[i];
}

for(i = 0; i < y; i++)
{
    MinOf(numbers[x, i, z]) = ymin[i];
    MaxOf(numbers[x, i, z]) = ymax[i];
}

for(i = 0; i < z; i++)
{
    MinOf(numbers[x, y, i]) = zmin[i];
    MaxOf(numbers[x, y, i]) = zmax[i];
}
```

Hopefully someone can help me with that.
Cheers, Phil13131

Comment: OT: just declare `i` in each loop.

Comment: C# does not support 'slices' at all. So you'll have to loop here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make methods for enumerating the slices. This is for one dimension, you would need another two, but I think you can manage that:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SliceX<T>(T[,,] data, int x) {
  for (int y = 0; y < data.GetLength(1); y++) {
    for (int z = 0; z < data.GetLength(2); z++) {
      yield return data[x, y, z];
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can just use the `Min` and `Max` methods, but that will of course loop through the data twice:

```
double min = SliceX(numbers, x).Min();
double max = SliceX(numbers, x).Max();
```

You can make an extension method that gets both min and max in one iteration:

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions {

  public static void GetMinMax<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data, out T min, out T max) where T : IComparable<T> {
    bool first = true;
    min = max = default(T);
    foreach (T value in data) {
      if (first) {
        min = max = value;
        first = false;
      } else {
        if (value.CompareTo(min) < 0) min = value;
        if (value.CompareTo(max) > 0) max = value;
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Usage:

```
double min, max;
SliceX(numbers, 0).GetMinMax(out min, out max);
```

Comment: Thank you, I have done something similar already, but I wanted to know if C# already has methods like that. After all they would probably be more efficient and also it would reduce my code by that method.

Comment: @phil13131: No, there is nothing built in for slicing arrays.

Comment: Okay thank you, I just tried out your method and the one above and accept the other one, because it is faster. But I learned something about IEnumerable, thanks to you =)

Comment: I now accepted your answer, as the other one doesn't always work (if numbers are negative).

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
double[, ,] numbers = new double[2, 2, 2];

numbers[0, 0, 0] = 0;
numbers[0, 0, 1] = 1;
numbers[0, 1, 0] = 2;
numbers[0, 1, 1] = 3;
numbers[1, 0, 0] = 4;
numbers[1, 0, 1] = 5;
numbers[1, 1, 0] = 6;
numbers[1, 1, 1] = 7;

double[] xmax = new double[numbers.GetLength(0)];
double[] ymax = new double[numbers.GetLength(1)];
double[] zmax = new double[numbers.GetLength(2)];

for (int x = 0; x < xmax.Length; x++) xmax[x] = int.MinValue;
for (int y = 0; y < ymax.Length; y++) ymax[y] = int.MinValue;
for (int z = 0; z < zmax.Length; z++) zmax[z] = int.MinValue;

for (int x = 0; x < xmax.Length; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < ymax.Length; y++)
        for (int z = 0; z < zmax.Length; z++)
        {
            xmax[x] = Math.Max(xmax[x], numbers[x, y, z]);
            ymax[y] = Math.Max(ymax[y], numbers[x, y, z]);
            zmax[z] = Math.Max(zmax[z], numbers[x, y, z]);
        }

// xmax == { 3, 7 }
// ymax == { 5, 7 }
// zmax == { 6, 7 }
```

Comment: It looks exactly like something I need, thank you very much! I don't know the class Enumerate but I will read about it.
The output is exactly what I expect. Could you please explain what the input `x: i` etc. means? I have never seen that.

Comment: Your code suddenly changed completely, your old method is gone and you replaced it. I see you simply loop over it, what happened to your old answer?

Comment: The Enumerable-based solution was nice, but this is much simpler and more efficient.

Comment: Note: The max arrays are initialised to zero, so this only works for positive numbers.

Comment: I think you method will not always work. I will have to loop over every slice and save the first value, as I can't expect 0 to be smaller than the biggest number (if numbers are all negative for example).
edit: as you just said...

Comment: Just fill xmax etc. with int.MinValue